# Magento-2 Custom payment method is not display in fornt side when JS is Merged

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, checkout-page

I have created a new custom payment method, it's working fine without Merge Js file.

When, I merge JS than it's not working in front-side.

I tried static-content-deploy & cache clean & clean browser cache.

But it does not work.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You have an error Js console? What’s the used navigator